# Error: Materialize output size (135581957) exceeded size limit (134217728)

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

I'm trying to read a large set of rows (several million) into Tableau.  I even tried throwing it into a temp table called 'temp' and just loading it as: `select * from session.temp` (Job ID: remilon-study:bquijob_6b12f7fe_15c0d8c603a), but that still gives me the error.  It doesn't tell me that I need to allowLargeResults, however when I pick a temporary table and check allowLargeResults it works.  Did the error message around this change at some point?  I used to get errors telling me to check allowLargeResults.

Unfortunately I can't find any way to tell Tableau to allowLargeResults.  According to [this](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_googlebigquery.html) Tableau documentation, Tableau should retry after it gets the result set too large error from BigQuery and I've seen that happen and work before, but that's not happening now.  I also can't find any documentation around "Materialize output size exceeded size limit" errors.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is wrong, and it is a bug in Standard SQL. If you switch (temporarily) back to Legacy SQL - you should get the old message about "AllowLargeResults", and hopefully it will cause Tableau to retry.